# Why is the value changing when I cast an int to an NSInteger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, int, nsinteger

I have an NSDictionary, and I perform **objectForKey** for key **resource_type_id**:

```
NSInteger resourceTypeID = [self.selectedDictionary objectForKey:@"resource_type_id"];
```

When I print **resourceTypeID** in the console, it returns **2** (the correct ID).

Now, I need to convert this NSInteger to an **int** to feed into my switch case statement.

Here is that code:

```
self.resourceTypeLabel.text = [ResourceType getResourceTypeFromResourceTypeID:(int)resourceTypeID];
```

However, when I do this, **self.resourceTypeLabel.text** returns **nil**.
Upon further inspection, when printing **(int)resourceTypeID** in the console, it returns **35**.

Why is the number changing when I cast it?

Answer (score 1):

`-objectForKey:` should return an *object* of type `id`, not an `int`. How are you setting the value?

Comment: The value that I'm getting out of the dictionary is an integer from a json object that I've fetched. Which value are you talking about setting?

Comment: No, it is no integer. Likely it is an `NSNumber` instance, built from an integer or an `NSString` instance. But you never get an integer from `-objectForKey:`.

Comment: Ok, got it--just changed `NSInteger` to `NSNumber` and then used `integerValue` and we're in business. Thanks y'all!